# Instalar Image Magick (imagick)

Tags: php, windows, iis-7

Tenho um servidor web local que utiliza Windows Server 2008 R2, o IIS7 é o gerenciador dos serviços web.
Instalei uma aplicação que necessita converter PDF para JPG, porém para isto necessito que o **Imagick** esteja instalado corretamente e configurado no PHP, em servidores de hospedagem, principalmente linux basta ativar esta extensão.
Já instalei o Imagick conforme sua documentação, baixei a .dll para PHP e coloquei da pasta /ext/ do PHP, depois ativei via painel ou php.ini

Mesmo após todo este processo o imagick não funciona no PHP, já via CMD ele funciona quando vou checar sua instalação.
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Verifique se a DLL que está utilizando é a mesma disponibilizada no repositório PECL: https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

Comment: Questão resolvida conforme o tópico:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26265214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questão resolvida com base no tópico (em inglês): 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26265214

Vale lembrar que os arquivos devem ser substituídos no local onde foi instalado o ImageMagick e em seguida a DLL chamada no php.ini manualmente na pasta de instalação.

Comment: Tiago pode marcar sua resposta como a correta? Acredito que você conseguiu resolver seu problema